# Akka.js TestKit: compilation error on simple example

Tags: javascript, scala, akka

I am using [akka.js](https://github.com/akka-js/akka.js) library and would like to create simple test case using akka's `TestKit` however whenever I extend from `akka.testkit.TestKit` I get the following exception:

```
[error] Could not run test Specification: scala.scalajs.js.JavaScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scheduler$3' of null
```

**Could you please provide any working example** as authors of library did not include it into their samples.

Versions of libraries used:

```
  "org.akka-js" %%% "akkajsactor" % "0.2.4.16",
  "org.akka-js" %%% "akkajstestkit" % "0.2.4.16" % Test
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the very late answer, could you provide a code example that you are using?
Currently you can fall into 2 main troubles using testkit:

1. Startup time
2. use of external resources

both are mentioned here: https://github.com/akka-js/akka.js#caveats

Basically you cannot access any external resource from the JS VM and you have to consider adding an `await()` call here and there if you are porting tests from JVM.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'scheduler$3' of null`

The object you are attempting to access the property of 'scheduler$3' appears to be null. Try verifying that it's source is properly retrieved. Can you provide more information and I could maybe give a more detailed answer?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, however it seems like issue is more related to the library and its documentation along with the set of provided examples rather  than understanding of the exception which is clear. Thanks for remark though I updated the question.